# Unmerge the branch from Git with sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-stash

How do i remove the purple merge that was highlighted in source tree?

I accidentally merged my branch to master and many devs committed on top of that, now I have to undo my merge from master but not delete it.

> [image: Git flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually revert a merge.

Here is an explanation of different possible ways: https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html

There is also the hard way: doing an interactive rebase https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History and stripping the unwanted merge commit. But probably, since you are asking this question in the first place, you should not walk this path.